# DBT: conditionally set schema config

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to determine how I can conditionally set schema config attributes. I've attempted this by a macro in both dbt_project.yml and also in schema.yml but both of these methods fail with:

```
00:23:19  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  Could not render {{get_location_root('lndv')}}: 'get_location_root' is undefined
```

The outcome I would like to achieve is conditionally setting *location_root* for Spark for various schemas. I want different locations for each environment. I thought the macro path was the best fit as this follows a pattern but it obviously doesn't work in *dbt_project.yml* or property files. I was using *target.name* to determine environment. It's in the same directory as other macros that are successfully rendering in models so the path is set correctly. I don't really want to resort to placing this config in each model if I can avoid it.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can solve this? Either getting the macro to work in *dbt_project.yml* / *schema.yml* or by some other method?

Regards,

Ashley

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dbt only allows a small subset of jinja in `.yml` files. In particular, you can't use macros. But you can use simple conditionals. Jinja that appears in `.yml` files must be quoted:

```yaml
schema: "{{ 'prod_schema' if target.name == 'production' else 'dev_schema' }}"
```

Another option for you is to override the built-in macro that generates schema names. There is a great write-up in the [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas#advanced-custom-schema-configuration) on this topic.

From the docs:

> If your dbt project includes a macro that is also named generate_schema_name, dbt will always use the macro in your dbt project instead of the default macro.
>
> Therefore, to change the way dbt generates a schema name, you should add a macro named generate_schema_name to your project, where you can then define your own logic.

There is even an alternative "non-default" version of this macro that ships with dbt, called `generate_schema_name_for_env`, with the logic:

> In prod:
>
> - If a custom schema is provided, a model's schema name should match the custom schema, rather than being concatenated to the target schema.
> - If no custom schema is provided, a model's schema name should match the target schema.
>
> In other environments (e.g. dev or qa):
>
> - Build all models in the target schema, as in, ignore custom schema configurations.

To use `generate_schema_name_for_env`, you create a new macro in your project with the following contents:

```sql
-- put this in macros/generate_schema_name.sql

{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    {{ generate_schema_name_for_env(custom_schema_name, node) }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

EDIT: In Spark, you can use a similar trick to set the "location" of the materialized model by overriding the [`location_clause` macro](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/ebd011ea71ba533e065cb167f6c8213753fa6e9e/dbt/include/spark/macros/adapters.sql#L13-L23) (which is part of the dbt-spark adapter). Your macro should template to a string with the word "location" followed by a path wrapped in single quotes:

```sql
{% macro location_clause() %}
  {%- set location_root = config.get('location_root', validator=validation.any[basestring]) -%}
  {%- set identifier = model['alias'] -%}
  {%- if location_root is not none and target.name == "production" %}
    location '{{ location_root }}/prod/{{ identifier }}'
  {%- elif location_root is not none %}
    location '{{ location_root }}/dev/{{ identifier }}'
  {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Comment: Thanks tconbeer. The first suggestion might do the trick but I don't think the generate_schema_name macro is going to work in this case. I'm not looking to set the actual schema attribute but rather the Spark specific location_root.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, didn’t realize it was about setting location_root, not schema. You should be able to define a custom macro called `location_clause` instead: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/ebd011ea71ba533e065cb167f6c8213753fa6e9e/dbt/include/spark/macros/adapters.sql#L13

Comment: I haven't tried it yet tconbeer, but that looks perfect! I'll give it a twirl shortly and report back.

Comment: Yep, that worked a treat! Thanks tconbeer.

Comment: Here's the macro I used for others that may be interersted:

Comment: `{% macro spark__location_clause() %}
  {%- set location_root = config.get('location_root', validator=validation.any[basestring]) -%}
  {%- set identifier = model['alias'] -%}
  {%- if location_root is not none -%}
  {%- if target.name == 'prod' %}
  {{ log("Production", info=true) }}
    location '/mnt/prod/private/raw/{{ location_root }}/{{ identifier }}'
  {%- else %}
  {{ log("Non-production", info=true) }}
    location '/mnt/dev/private/raw/{{target.schema}}_{{ location_root }}/{{ identifier }}'
  {%- endif %}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro -%}`

Comment: I didn't use a path in the dbt_profile.yml for location_root. Just the raw schema name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the syntax in source yml config is a little weird for if/elif/else:

project: '{{var("output_project_dev") if target.name == "dev" else var("output_project_prod") if target.name == "prod" else var("third_project") }}'