# dbt: parametize path of external tables based on the target environment

Tags: databricks, dbt

I'm using dbt + databricks
I'm using external delta tables so need to explicitly specify a location for the materialized='table' models

I can't see anything in the doco about how to do this. Are there any defined patterns?

here's the relevant section from the dbt_project.yml

```
models:
  +file_format: delta
  cdp:
    DataMart:
       +location_root: "abfss://deltalake@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/DataMart/"
    MarketAnalytics:
       +location_root: "abfss://deltalake@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/MarketAnalytics/"    
       Staging:
          +location_root: "abfss://deltalake@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/Staging/"
    Ref:
       +location_root: "abfss://deltalake@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/Ref/"
```

I need to be able to pass a different prod path in the location root when I run the built using the prod target. I dont want to have to manage multiple projects based on the env

Comment: The solution to your issue looks very simple but your question is ambiguous, consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern; you have two options for how to achieve this, but the best way is probably to override the macro that dbt uses to build the fully-qualified name/path of the database relation. For most adapters you would override the macro called `generate_schema_name`, but for Spark adapters, you need to override the macro called `location_clause`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73563223/dbt-conditionally-set-schema-config/73589026#73589026) for more details (there is an example target-aware `location_clause` macro at the end).

A simpler, but more repetitive option, is to use a little jinja in your yml files. Note that you cannot call a macro from the jinja inside of yml files, but simple branching logic does work (you need to quote the whole thing)

```yaml
models:
  +file_format: delta
  cdp:
    DataMart:
       +location_root: "abfss://deltalake@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/DataMart/{{ '' if target.name == 'production' else 'dev/'}}"
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, I've modified the generate_schema macro for other reasons before but didn't think it covered this scenario as well. I couldn't find any doco that defines the 'target.name' type variables/properties that are available and their scope.  I've gone the simple method - +location_root: "abfss://deltalake@{{ '' if target.name == 'prod' 'prod_storage_acc' else 'dev_storage_acc'}}.dfs.core.windows.net/DataMart/"