# Working with multiple data warehouses in dbt

Tags: amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, dbt

I'm building an application where each of our clients needs their own data warehouse (for security, compliance, and maintainability reasons). For each client we pull in data from multiple third party integrations and then merge them into a unified view, which we use to perform analytics and report metrics for the data across those integrations. These transformations and all relevant schemas are the same for all clients. We would need this to scale to 1000s of clients.

From what I gather dbt is designed so each project corresponds with one warehouse. I see two options:

1. Use one project and create a separate environment target for each client (and maybe a single dev environment). Given that environments aren't designed for this, are there any catches to this? Will scheduling, orchestrating, or querying the outputs be painful or unscalable for some reason?

profiles.yml:

```
example_project:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: redshift
      ...
    client_1:
      type: redshift
      ...
    client_2:
      type: redshift
      ...
    ...
```

2. Create multiple projects, and create a shared dbt package containing most of the logic. This seems very unwieldy needing to maintain a separate repo for each client and less developer friendly.

profiles.yml:

```
client_1_project:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    client_1:
      type: redshift
      ...
client_2_project:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    client_2:
      type: redshift
      ...
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you captured both options.

If you have a single database connection, and your client data is logically separated in that connection, I would definitely pick #2 (one package, many client projects) over #1. Some reasons:

1. Selecting data from a different source (within a single connection), depending on the target, is a bit [hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73563223/dbt-conditionally-set-schema-config/73589026#73589026), and wouldn't scale well for 1000's of clients.
2. The developer experience for packages isn't so bad. You will want a developer data source, but depending on your business you could maybe get away with using one client's data (or an anonymized version of that). It will be good to keep this developer environment logically separate from any individual client's implementation, and packages allow you to do that.
3. I would consider generating the client projects programmatically, probably using a Python CLI to set up, `dbt run`, and tear down the required files for each client project (I'm assuming you're not going to use dbt Cloud and have another orchestrator or compute environment that you control). It's easy to write YAML from Python with `pyyaml` (each file is just a dict), and your individual projects probably only need separate `profiles.yml`, `sources.yml`, and (maybe) `dbt_project.yml` files. I wouldn't check these generated files for each client into source control -- just check in the script and generate the files you need with each invocation of dbt.

On the other hand, if your clients each have their own physical database with separate connections and credentials, and those databases are absolutely identical, you could get away with #1 (one project, many profiles). The "hardest" parts of that approach would likely be managing secrets and generating/maintaining a list of targets that you could iterate over (ideally in a parallel fashion).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I can see how specifying dynamic data sources/schemas in schema.yml or dbt_project.yml would be hacky, but if I only need to source information to live in profiles.yml as separate environments, I don't think I would need any of that special logic. The schema configs will be the same for every client.

Could you please elaborate on what wouldn't scale well in option 1?

Programmatically generating the .yml wouldn't be a problem, but it would feel like an anti-pattern to source controls different files for every client, and having dynamic variables would feel hacky.

Comment: oh, I see, your client databases have their own connection info? So physically separate databases?

Comment: yeah, each has their own Redshift cluster

Comment: Got it. That does make #1 a lot more appealing. I'd be tempted to go that route, in that case. You'll want a secrets manager and a way to generate a list of all the targets that you can iterate over (and ideally parallelize), but that doesn't seem too bad? To clarify my point #3, though, I probably wouldn't check in every client's code to source control, I'd just check in the generating script. You could generate the files you need on the fly when you want to run a client's project.

Comment: I see - that makes sense, thanks. If you want to update your answer with I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: added. interesting problem to think about!